# text-shadow with opacity

Tags: css

I can use text-shadow opacity as following:

```
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(85,0,0,.5);/* 50% opacity */
```

But I don't have control over selecting color value. So I want to do just this:

```
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
```

This is because text-color may vary and I want to apply the color for text-shadow as same as text-color.

So, is there any technique to apply opacity for color value without selecting the color?

Comment: you can apply css opacity to the whole text 
allthough if you want to alter the opacity of the text shadow - then there is no known way to me besides using rgb with the alpha channel

Comment: Seeing the "prototype" of this CSS rule, `text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;`, you may want to write it like following to get rid of the color : `text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px initial;`.

Comment: and text-shadow color opacity?

Comment: Basically...you cannot do this with CSS. You'll need either javascript or an alternative method of creating the tetx-shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to get the desired look with a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

- Give the element a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes) attribute:

  ```
  <h2 data-text="this is how it works">this is how it works</h2>
  ```
- The text can now be displayed with `content: attr(data-text)` in a [`:before`](http://devdocs.io/css/::before). It will inherit the colour of its parent element and the `opacity` property can be used:

  ```
  h2:before {
      content: attr(data-text);
      position: absolute;
      left: 3px;
      top: 3px;
      opacity: 0.1;
  }
  ```

The result:

[image: Example]

#### Example

I have also included a rough example of how this can be applied automatically with javascript / jQuery.

```js
var string = $('h1').text();
$('h1').attr('data-text', string);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  color: #F00;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  color: #F09;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1:before,
h2:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Give me shadow</h1>

<h2 data-text="this is how it works">this is how it works</h2>
```

Comment: This is good one. but without using data-text would be fine. But I hope there's no way beyond this. So, accepting this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want to following this?**

use **RGB** color into text shadow `rgba(red_value,green_value,blue_value, opacity)`

**Update**

```css
p {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0 10px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, .3)
}
```

```html
<p>Example text</p>
```

Comment: this would be opacity for text-color not for text-shadow color

Answer (score -1):

If I've understand your question, the `color` in `text-shadow` is optional and it takes the color of the text as default so you can use

```
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
color: rgb(85,0,0); // or whatever you need
opacity: 0.5; // or whatever you need
```

See [text-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow), [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

Comment: use filter: Alpha(opacity=50); for IE8 and before ;-)

Comment: this would be opacity for text-color not for text-shadow color